# How to run grunt-connect within docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker, grunt-contrib-connect

I have Grunt running a node connect (grunt-contrib-connect) web server on `localhost:8080` in a docker container. I run the container with this command:
`$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 js1972/yeoman:v3`.

Inside my container I run the grunt connect task with `grunt develop`.

I'm on a Mac so using boot2docker. `boot2docker ip` says the host ip is 192.168.59.103 so I should access the connect server with http://192.168.59.103:8080 in my browser.

However this doesn't work and I just get a safari can't connect to server message. (note that the port forwarding works just fine when I use a simple python web server like on the docker website examples.)

Any idea whats wrong here? The same process works perfectly well outside of docker.
I've got a feeling its something to do with running Connect on localhost. I've tried various combinations of --add-hosts and -p localhost:8080:8080 and so on to no avail...

If it helps here's my docker file and gruntfile:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7546923/Dockerfile
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7546923/Gruntfile.js

Rgds, Jason.

Comment: try changing "localhost" in connect to "0.0.0.0"

Comment: Thanks Adrian - that did the trick and I would NEVER have thought of it. Need to read up on the difference between 0.0.0.0, localhost and 127.0.0.1 now.   ;-)

Comment: Cool. 0.0.0.0 just listens to all network interfaces. 127.0.0.1 only listens to the local loopback interface IIRC. I'll add an answer if that's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`.

At the moment the container is only listening for *internal* connections on the local interface. Using `0.0.0.0` will tell it to listen to all interfaces including the one the Docker host is connected to.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the ip of the hostname in the connect settings of the Gruntfile:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 8080,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    livereload: 35729
  },
```

And open the server and reload port to the boot2docker vm:

```
boot2docker poweroff # vm needs to be off to modify the network settings
VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "containergruntserver,tcp,,8080,,8080"
VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "containergruntreload,tcp,,35729,,35729"
boot2docker up
```